# What are the charge densities on the inner and outer surface of a thin metallic spherical shell, if it contains an electric dipole inside it?

Tags: electrostatics

In my opinion both charge densities should be zero following from the fact that the electric field on any spherical gaussian surface is zero, so no charge redistribution of the metallic shell will take place. Consequently, there won't be any accumulation of charges on the inner and outer surface of the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the Laplace's equation in various regions and matching boundary conditions (assuming $\phi(\infty)=0$) you got the trivial solution $\phi = 0$ both inside (from inner radius to outer radius) and outside the shell. Hence there is no field in these two regions and so the charge density on the outer surface is everywhere zero.

For the region with the dipole, with the general solution
$$\phi(r,\theta)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty \left(A_lr^l+\frac{B_l}{r^{l+1}}\right)P_l(\cos\theta)$$
and by matching boundary condition at $r=0$, we have (assuming WLOG the dipole be in the $z$ direction, and inner radius equals $R$)
$$B_1=\frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$$
$$A_1=-\frac{B_1}{R^3}=-\frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0R^3}$$
$$A_l=B_l=0$$
for all $l\ne 1$.

Hence
$$\phi(r,\theta)=\frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(-\frac{r}{R^3}+\frac{1}{r^2}\right)\cos\theta$$

The field at $R$ is
$$\vec{E}(R,\theta)=-\left(\hat{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\hat{\theta}\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\right)\phi(r,\theta)\bigg|_{r=R}$$
$$=-\hat{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\phi(r,\theta)\bigg|_{r=R}$$
$$=\hat{r}\frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{3}{R^3}\cos\theta$$

Therefore
$$\sigma(\theta)=-\frac{3p}{4\pi R^3}\cos\theta$$

Remark: The problem can also be solved by image charge method.

Answer (score 1):

For the outer shell you are correct, but the inner shell will probably have some redistribution of density to minimize its energy with the dipole inside - the net charge on the inner surface will be zero, but the charge will not be distributed evenly because of the dipole inside.

This is a very very rough sketch of the sort of thing....

[image]

it is not meant to be quantitative, but the charges on the ends of the dipole are greater than the individual bits on the sphere surface - and the bits on the surface represent a smooth distribution density of charge.